# AWS Timestream With Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I am currently working on a project that utilizes an amazon timestream database. I am attempting to pull the information from the database using node to populate a dashboard, but I have no clue how to link the database to the node script. I have the AWS certification set up but can not get the server to connect for a query.

Answer (score 2):

AWS has an SDK for this. For Timestream, check out the following:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-timestream-write/index.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-timestream-query/index.html

The required AWS credentials can be configured as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html.